# Reading data from Windows resource (.res) file in Python?

Tags: python, resources, cross-platform

I have a Windows .res file, and I want to read its data in Python.

The file looks like this in [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/):
[image: Resource Hacker - data.res]

I need something like this:

```
>>> data = read_res_file("data.res")
>>> data.str_table["1"]["1"]
'Test'
>>> data.str_table["1"]["2"]
'Another test'
```

What is the best way to do so in Python 3?
The solution should be cross-platform and for Python 3.